# Powershell v3.0 pipe issue

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I'm having trouble with this command:

```
gc .\domains.txt | Get-ADDomain
```

As the name implies, domains.txt contains a list of Active Directory to query (all domains are in the same forest).

If I run it on my Windows 8 machine everything works fine and I get the expected results, instead on a Windows 2008 R2 SP1 member server (not a DC) with WMF 3.0 I get result only from the first domain in the list and for the others:

```
Get-ADDomain : A referral was returned from the server
```

If I query a domain in the list with:

```
Get-ADDomain <Domain name here>
```

it works fine.

## My Workstation

Microsoft Windows 8 Enterprise (6.2.9200) x64

```
PS D:\Tools\Powershell> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      3.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18010
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.16384
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

## Server

Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1 (6.1.7601) x64

```
PS C:\Tools\Powershell> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.16398
PSVersion                      3.0
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.269
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

## Update

If i run on the server:

```
gc .\domains.txt | %{ Get-ADDomain $_ }
```

it runs fine

## TRACE

```
trace-command -Name ParameterBinding { "DOMAIN_1","DOMAIN_2" | Get-ADDomain } -PSHost
```

Server: http://pastebin.com/sRVJHaCU

Workstation: http://pastebin.com/kj3JV6nV

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the first domain (on which it's working in Server 2008 R2) the domain this server belongs to ?

Comment: no, the server belongs to a domain which return the error (using the pipe)

Comment: Do you double check the text file (no special characters at the end of the lines, unicode/ansi misfit) ?

Comment: Yes, it's generated from (Get-ADForest <ForestName>).Domains | Out-File domains.txt; I've also tried to recreate it by hand with notepad with a subset of domains.

Comment: Are you identified as the same user, on your compuper, and on the server when you lounch the script ?

Comment: Try using Trace-Command to see how the parameter binding is failing e.g. `trace-command -Name ParameterBinding { gc .\domains.txt | Get-ADDomain } -PSHost`

Comment: Do the two machines point on the same DNS ?

Comment: Trace from server: http://pastebin.com/sRVJHaCU 
Trace from workstation: http://pastebin.com/kj3JV6nV

It seems like ActiveDirectory module is misbehaving on server.

Actually the two machines point to different DNS; i'll try with same DNS servers.

Comment: +1 EsOsO - this smells like DNS issue.  make sure the server is pointing to the correct DNS server.

Comment: @EsOsO Those pastebin links are broken, says "Unknown Paste ID".

Comment: you'll might want to add the information in pastebin to the question itself...

Comment: Just curious, what is the functional level of the forest, and is there a difference between the functional level of the working domain and the broken ones?

Comment: Have you enabled the event viewer logs for powershell? In event viewer, expand Applications and Service Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Powershell. Enable analytic logs in the menu. Then enable log (on the right side) on operational and analytic. It shows details about remoting in there and may point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I found an article that may help.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617224.aspx

From the look of your script you are providing the server using the text file.  Is it possible the problem is the Windows 2008 server you are running the PowerShell script on is not in the same domain or the user you are logged in as does not have access to the domains where the other servers are members?

snippet from the above article:

> -If the Server parameter is specified and the Credential parameter is not specified:
>   --The domain is set to the domain of the specified server and the cmdlet checks to make sure that the server is in the domain of the
>   LocalComputer or LoggedOnUser. Then the credentials of the current
>   logged on user are used to get the domain. An error is returned when
>   the server is not in the domain of the LocalComputer or LoggedOnUser.

You might try adding the additional parameters for the Get-ADDomain commandlet such as -Identity, -AuthType, and -Credential

> Get-ADDomain [-Identity]  [-AuthType { |
>   }] [-Credential ] [-Server ]
>   []

Comment: You are right the server is joined to a domain and i'm trying to get info of others domain in the forest, but i still can't understand why gc .\domains.txt | %{ Get-ADDomain $_ } works, while gc .\domains.txt | Get-ADDomain does not.

Answer (score 0):

[Powershell v3.0 pipe issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192447/powershell-v3-0-pipe-issue)

I just tried to run the cmdlet 'gc .\text.txt | Get-ADDomain' from a virtual Server 2008 R2 box that I have. I built a text file in the following format:

```
 Domain1
 Domain2
 Domain3
```

One thing to be sure of is that each domain is on it's own line in the text file. I can understand why the one syntax worked when you piped the STDOUT to:

```
%{ Get-ADDomain $_}
```

because you are looping through all the information contained in the text file and only have the cmdlet work on a single value at a time. Unfortunately I don't have the RSAT package on my Win 8 desktop, so I can't test from my desktop. Hopefully this helps a little bit.